# Incompatible Types in Java. Hope for some assistance

Tags: java, bluej, incompatibletypeerror

I'm fairly new to `Java` and I'm using `BlueJ`. I keep getting the error:

```
incompatible types
```

Now that sounds self explanatory, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix the problem. Hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance.

Here is the code to the `class Program2`:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        Catalog store = new Catalog(3);
        int itemnum;
        Item item;

        try {
            store.insert
              (new Music(1111, "Gold", 12.00, "Abba"));
            store.insert
              (new Movie(2222, "Mamma Mia", 16.00, "Meryl Streep"));
            store.insert
              (new Book(3333, "DaVinci Code", 8.00, "Dan Brown"));
              store.insert
            (new Music(4444, "Legend", 15.00, "Bob Marley"));
            } catch (CatalogFull exc) {
                System.out.println(exc);
            }

        //  Insert code here to perform a sequence of
        //  interactive transactions with the user.
        //  The user enters an item number and the program
        //  either displays the item or prints an error message
        //  if the item is not found.  The program terminates
        //  when the user enters zero as the item number.

        while (!item.equals("0")) {
            item = store.find(itemnum);
            if (item != null) {
                System.out.print(itemnum);
            } else {
                System.out.printf("%s was not found.%n", item);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Player (0 to exit)? ");
            itemnum = kbd.next(); //Error on "()"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: look at the documentation for `Scanner.next()`, and the type of the variable you're trying to assign the value to. Now look for other methods on `Scanner` that might help you more...

Comment: In what context does this error appear (i.e. what are you doing to trigger it)?  And is there any other error associated with it, e.g. a line number or stack trace?

Comment: It would help if you coul tell us what line the error occurs.

Comment: @X.L.Ant missed that one. My bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*String is not assignable to integer*

Use `nextInt()`  since `itemnum`  is `int` , where as `next()`  returns `String`, Thus incompatible types.

```
itemnum = kbd.nextInt();
```

not

```
itemnum = kbd.next();
```

[And see different type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: I'd change the first line to "String is not *assignable to* integer", since equality has a specific meaning in Java (i.e. `Object.equals()`) that's not relevant here.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle Yup. Edited :)  improper selection of words :(